# crystal report Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Hi friend I've created a crystal report with parameter,its running successfully in while executing in source code but it does not load in while i config after IIS its shows the error like unable to connect log on parameters. Please check my code and correct me.

hi frinds if i comment the  oStream = (MemoryStream)reportdocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat); this line and  Response.BinaryWrite(oStream.ToArray()); this report is generate in IIS but i not get in proper pdf formate pls help me i want to generate in pdf formate pls guide me

```
public partial class frm_MRPrint : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conn"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            mr();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MemoryStream oStream;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;


        ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();

        reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("MR.rpt"));
        reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin123", "vivek", "PURCHASE");

        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("MRNO", ddlmrno.SelectedItem.Text);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;

        oStream = (MemoryStream)reportdocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        try
        {

            //write report to the Response stream

            Response.BinaryWrite(oStream.ToArray());

            Response.End();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.Text = "ERROR:" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message.ToString());


        }

        finally
        {

            //clear stream

            oStream.Flush();

            oStream.Close();

            oStream.Dispose();

        }

        //in case you want to export it as an attachment use the line below

        //crReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Your Exported File Name");

    }

    public void mr()
    {

        ddlmrno.Items.Clear();
        ListItem frstitem = new ListItem();
        frstitem.Text = "- Select -";
        ddlmrno.Items.Add(frstitem);
        ddlmrno.SelectedIndex = 0;
        Con.Open();
        string sql = "";
        sql = "select  distinct(MRNO) from dbo.tbl_KKSMR where status=1 order by MRNO asc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Con);
        SqlDataReader rdr;
        try
        {
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                newItem.Text = rdr["MRNO"].ToString().Trim();
                newItem.Value = rdr["MRNO"].ToString().Trim();
                ddlmrno.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();

        } Con.Close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is Aspx File.....

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
                    AutoDataBind="true" oninit="CrystalReportViewer1_Init"  />
```

This is Cs file.....

```
      using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
        using System.Reflection;
        using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
        using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
        using CrystalDecisions.Reporting;
        using CrystalDecisions;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Data;
        using BusinessAccessLevel;
        using BusinessAccessLevel.Masters;

        namespace TexERP.ReportCrystal.Sales
        {
            public partial class CityReportCry : System.Web.UI.Page
            {
                ReportDocument doc;
            }

         protected void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    OldLoadReport();            
                }

              private void OldLoadReport()
                {
                    doc = new ReportDocument();
                    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("MR.rpt"));
               doc.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin123", "vivek", "PURCHASE", false);
               reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@MRNO", ddlmrno.SelectedValue);
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
                }

                protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    OldLoadReport();
                }
            }
        }
```

Code for Directly Export to .Pdf

```
                ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
                DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
                CrExportOptions = doc.ExportOptions;
                {
                    CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                    CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                    CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                    CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                }
                doc.Export();
```

Comment: Dear friend, here wat u have thought me to do for my error, have been tried and got the same error.. so please give me a another suggestion. wait for ur rply

Comment: Hi friend while i used ur code it running successfully and i get the report through the IIS thank you but i want generate in pdf formate please guide me

Comment: ya i gave in the property printmode is pdf but it not working

Comment: What u actually want.....????? I think u want directly export in pdf on show report click.........

Comment: Ya i want to export directly in pdf

Comment: RptDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "application/pdf");

Comment: chetan if i use this code it shows like incorrect log on parameter

Comment: Put it below  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc; line

Comment: doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("MR.rpt"));
        doc.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin123", "vivek", "PURCHASE", false);
        doc.SetParameterValue("MRNO", ddlmrno.SelectedValue);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
        doc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "application/pdf");

Comment: private void OldLoadReport()
    {
        doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("MR.rpt"));
        doc.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "Admin123", "vivek", "PURCHASE", false);
        doc.SetParameterValue("MRNO", ddlmrno.SelectedValue);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
        doc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,                             "application/pdf");
    }

Comment: Apply the code Which i  give u named Export to directly Pdf .see it tn the main code....

Comment: this code is not work it shows the same error only but i get the report as pdf and in that not have saveas option like that how to get that options and all

Comment: chetan while i check this your code using break point it shows error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object. wheile crossing this line CrExportOptions = doc.ExportOptions;

Comment: what to give here between this double quots"c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";

Comment: You have to set the path where you want to save your pdf file

Comment: Thank you friends i finally finish successfull and generate my report in pdf formate thank u very much thanks lot..

Comment: You are Welcome.......If My ans is completely worked ? Then plz mark it as a right.....

Answer (score 0):

it is an access issue . in your web.config

```
<identity impersonate="true|false" 
          userName="domain\username"
          password="password"/>
```

give the administrator credentials . and give your project folder , proper rights .it will work .

Answer (score 0):

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, also check if your report's Datasource provider is "SQL Native Client". If yes, this wont work in your Production server which doesn't have SQL client installed. It has to be "SQLOLEDB" for it work in machines where there is no SQL client installed.

This was the reason why my report worked on my test server(which had SQL server client) and did not work in my production server.

In some scenarios, it has nothing to do with the logon credentials. Crystal reports gives that error when it cant talk to the provider you specified.